# function to average numbers from input without limit

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I wanna make code that getting number from input until the number is `"-1"(==-1)`
and then with that numbers, I wanna make average.
So I code like this

I wanna know why my code makes an error

```
print("if u wanna quit inputting number, press '-1'")
print("="*60)

a=[]
while input()!=-1:
    a.append(int(input()))

def avrg(*n):
    summ=0
    avrg=0
    for i in n:
        summ+=i
    avrg=summ/len(n)
    return avrg

b=avrg(a)
print(b)
```

and even though I enter `'-1'`, the function isn't work

Comment: `int(input()) != -1` or `input() != "-1"`?

Comment: Also make sure you explain __what__ doesn't work exactly: gives an error? doesn't stop the loop? Final result is wrong? ...

Comment: You probably don't want to call `input` both in your while conditional and inside the while loop.

Comment: `input()` returns a `string`. Comparing it with an `int` (-1) will always return `False` (and `!=` will always be `True`).

Answer (score 2):

You likely don't want to call `input` both in your while conditional and inside the while loop. Something like this is probably what you are going for:

```
a = []
num = int(input())
while num != -1:
    a.append(num)
    num = int(input())
```

Also, your averaging is a little more complicated than needed. Try this:

```
b = sum(a) / len(a)
```

Of course, you are going to run into trouble if you don't input any numbers to average, that is dividing by 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("if u wanna quit inputting number, press '-1'")
print("="*60)

a=[]

while True:
    i = int(input())
    if i==-1:
        break
    else:
        a.append(i)

def avrg(a):
    return sum(a)/len(a)

b=avrg(a)
print(b)
```

User input from the function `input()` is always of type `str`, so you should need to convert it to `int` before the comparison `if i==-1`. 
In the while loop, it continues to consume user input, until user inputs `-1`.
The sum of a list can be simply calculated by the built-in function `sum`.

Comment: Code-only answers are fine. But I suggest adding an explanation so that readers will know _why_ your solution works.